# linux logrotate how to set rules for all log files in an directory(including files in sub-directory)

Tags: linux, shell, logrotate

For example, I want to set rules for all files under `/home/example_user/public/` and all logs are actually located in different sub-directories like this: `/home/example_user/public/siteA/access.log`, `/home/example_user/public/siteB/seperate/error.log`, etc. What should I do? Would this do the trick:

```
/home/example_user/public/*/*.log {
weekly
missingok
rotate 10
blahblahblah...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes the logrotate configuration which you have provided will work.